# Consolidating 300+ files into 5-8, OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#

I have 369 files that need to be formatted and consolidated into 5-8 files before being submitted to the server.  I can't submit the 369 files because that would overwhelm the metadata tables in our database (they can handle it, but it'd be 369 rows for what was essentially one file, which would make querying and utilizing those tables a nightmare) and I can't handle it as one file because the total of 3.6 GB is too much for SSIS to handle on our servers.

I wrote the following script to fix the issue:

```
        static void PrepPAIDCLAIMSFiles()
        {
            const string HEADER = "some long header text, trimmed for SO question";
            const string FOOTER = "some long footer text, trimmed for SO question";
            //path is defined as a static member of the containing class
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path + @"split\");  
            int splitFileCount = 0, finalFileCount = 0;
            List<string> newFileContents = new List<string>();
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    var contents = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
                    var fs = File.OpenRead(file);
                    if (splitFileCount == 0)
                    {
                        //Grab everything except the header
                        contents = contents.GetRange(1, contents.Count - 1);
                    }
                    else if (splitFileCount == files.Length - 1)
                    {
                        //Grab everything except the footer
                        contents = contents.GetRange(0, contents.Count - 1);
                    }
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path + @"split\formatted"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + @"split\formatted");
                    }
                    newFileContents.AddRange(contents);
                    if (splitFileCount % 50 == 0 || splitFileCount >= files.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{splitFileCount} {finalFileCount}");
                        var sb = new StringBuilder(HEADER);
                        foreach (var row in newFileContents)
                        {
                            sb.Append(row);
                        }
                        sb.Append(FOOTER);
                        newFileContents = new List<string>();
                        GC.Collect();
                        string fileName = file.Split('\\').Last();
                        string baseFileName = fileName.Split('.')[0];
                        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                        baseFileName += "." + COMPANY_NAME_SetHHMMSS(currentTime, finalFileCount) + ".TXT";
                        File.WriteAllText(path + @"split\formatted\" + baseFileName, sb.ToString());
                        finalFileCount += 1;
                    }
                    splitFileCount += 1;
                }
                catch(OutOfMemoryException OOM)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                    Console.WriteLine(OOM.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The way this works is it reads the split file, puts its rows into a string builder, every time it gets to a multiple of 50 files, it writes the string builder to a new file and starts over.  The `COMPANY_NAME_SetHHMMSS()` method ensures the file has a unique name, so it's not writing to the same file over and over (and I can verify this by seeing the output, it writes two files before exploding.)

It breaks when it gets to the 81st file.  `System.OutOfMemoryException` on `var contents = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();`.  There's nothing special about the 81st file, it's the same exact size as all the others (~10MB.)  The files this function delivers are about ~500MB.  It also has no trouble reading and processing all the files upto and not including the 81st, so I don't think that it's running out of memory reading the file, but running out of memory doing something else and it's at the 81st where memory runs out.

The `newFileContents()` list should be getting emptied by overwriting it with a new list, right?  That shouldn't be growing with every iteration in this function.  `GC.Collect()` was sort of a last ditch effort.

The original file that the 369 splits come from has been a headache for a few days now, causing UltraEdit to crash, SSIS to crash, C# to crash, etc.  Splitting it via 7zip seemed to be the only option that worked, and splitting it to 369 files seemed to be the only option 7zip had that didn't also reformat or somehow compress the file in an undesirable way.

Is there something that I'm missing?  Something in my code that keeps growing in memory?  I know `File.ReadAllLines()` opens and closes the file, so it should be disposed after called, right?  `newFileContents()` gets overwritten every 50th file, as does the string builder.  What else could I be doing?

Comment: Am I missing any usage of `using` anywhere?  Do you implement garbage collection and/or handling separately somewhere?  EDIT: Nevermind, I see the one GC collect now.

Comment: So, so not read all the lines into memory. Seriously, there is zero need to actually read them into memory. Change your algorithm.

Comment: That's a good point - an iterative process as @TomTom pointed out - may show you a more specific point (maybe a bad line, bad encoding, etc.) where this is failing.

Comment: Try using windows do to the work :  File.AppendAllText("destintation Filename", File.ReadAllText("source Filename"));

Answer (score 2):

One thing that jumps out at me is that you are opening a FileStream, never using it, and never disposing of it. With 300+ file streams this may be contributing to your issue.

```
var fs = File.OpenRead(file);
```

Another thing that perked my ear is that you said 3.6GB. Make sure you are compiling for 64 bit architecture.

Finally, stuffing gigabytes into a string builder may cause you grief. Maybe create a staging file - which every time you open a new input file, you write that to the staging file, close the input, and not depend on stuffing everything into memory.

Comment: oh that one line should have been deleted.  It's an error but not the problem, as I had the exception before I wrote that. I was using intellisense to see what methods might be useful and forgot to remove it.

I think I'll try what you suggest, that sounds very doable.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be looping over the rows in your source files and appending them to a new file. You're holding the contents of up to 50 10MB files in memory at once, plus anything else you're doing. This may be because you're compiling for x86 instead of x64, but there isn't any reason this should use anywhere near that memory. Something like the following:

```
        var files = Directory.Getfiles(System.IO.Path.Combing(path, "split")).ToList();
        //since you were skipping the first and last file
        files.Remove(files.FirstOrDefault());
        files.Remove(files.LastOrDefault());

        string combined_file_path = "<whatever you want to call this>";
        System.IO.StreamWriter combined_file_writer = null;
        try
        {
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                //if multiple of 50, write footer, dispose of stream, and make a new stream
                if((files.IndexOf(file)) % 50 == 0)
                {
                    combined_file_writer?.WriteLine(FOOTER);
                    combined_file_writer?.Dispose();
                    combined_file_writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(combined_file_path + "_1"); //increment the name somewhow
                    combined_file_writer.WriteLine(Header);
                }

                using(var file_reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file))
                {
                    while(!file_reader.EOF)
                    {
                        combined_file_writer.WriteLine(file_reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                }

            }

            //finish out the last file
            combined_file_writer?.WriteLine(FOOTER);
        }
        finally
        {
            //dispose of last file
            combined_file_writer?.Dispose();
        }
```